# Message Fusion Function

Tags: python

Im an intro python student and in one of my assignments im asked to incorporate a message fusion function by converting a string type into integer and back to string. The explicit instructions are :

Paths for the two files that you will require for this task has been stored in variables `file_path_1` and `file_path_2`

Call the function `read_file()` written in the previous task for `file_path_1` & `file_path_2` and store their message sentences in variables `message_1` and `message_2` respectively.

Print `message_1` and `message_2` to see what they contain.

Write a function `fuse_msg()` that :

- Takes `message_a` and `message_b` as parameters
- Implements integer(floor) division of `message_b` over `message_a`(Don't forget to make messages as int before applying floor division) and stores the quotient in a variable called `quotient`
- Returns `quotient` in string format

Call the function fuse_msg() with message_1 & message_2 and store the result of it in a variable called secret_msg_1

my code is :

```
message_1 = read_file(file_path_1)
message_2 = read_file(file_path_2)

print(message_1)
print(message_2)

def fuse_msg(message_b, message_a):
    quotient = (int(message_b)//int(message_a))
    return str(quotient)

secret_msg_1 = fuse_msg(message_1, message_2)
print(secret_msg_1)
```

... I keep receiving en error claiming that:

```
You have not extracted content for 'message_1' correctly.
It should be '2222'

You have not extracted content for 'message_2' correctly.

It should be '2477'
```

Comment: The error says the result of ``read_file`` is incorrect. We cannot help you without knowing the function and its input. What values *do* you read instead of the expected ones?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Is right, please add the code for read_file and content of the files you are reading (once from notepad and once the printed value your code outputs)